# how to update a cell value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

```
 filename = r'C:\Users\91956\Desktop\File.csv'
 df = pd.read_csv(filename)
 ss = WebSocket(FEED_TOKEN, CLIENT_CODE)
    

def on_tick(ws, tick):
      ltp = tick[0]['ltp']
      token = tick[0]['tk']
      df['ltp'][df.tk == token] = ltp
        
ss.on_ticks = on_tick
ss.connect()

st.write(df)
```

dataframe `df`  contains columns `tk` and and `ltp`.

i want to change the values in column `ltp`, using the tick data, so i am doing this,

```
df['ltp'][df.tk == token] = ltp
```

i am getting this waring

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df['ltp'][df.tk == token] = ltp
```

i tried to visit the page from above link ,but it doesnt exist.

i am displaying dataframe using streamlit,
and i expect to see the value in cells of `ltp` column to change
but that doesnt happen

this means `df['ltp'][df.tk == token] = ltp`  is not updating  `df`,

how to do this?

**update:**
after using `loc`, i am getting this error

```
   raise IndexingError(key) from e
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: ('ltp', 0      False
1      False
2      False
3      False
4      False
       ...
154    False
155    False
156    False
157    False
158    False
Name: tk, Length: 159, dtype: bool)
```

Comment: See my answer on the correct use of `.loc`

Comment: @SeaBean  yes your answer is correct,

Comment: @SeaBean  where should i write st.write(df)  so that the updated dataframe is displayed  in browser, i tried to write it in on_tick function, but it created a new dataframe for each update.  i want the single dataframe to get updated.

Comment: You should put it outside of the on_tick function and probably at the end of processing other updates.

Comment: i wrote it at end, it doesnt update the dataframe

Comment: I seen you defined `ss` for the WebSocket but used a different name `st` for write.  Is this normal ?

Comment: yes it is normal,  i have imported streamlit as st                                                                           i have asked a question here https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/show-realtime-data-using-dataframe/13423                                                                                                                if you have experience with streamlit please answer.

Comment: I suggest you can also post your question in Stackoverflow here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with the first parameter as condition and the second parameter as column name, as follows:

```
df.loc[df.tk == token, 'ltp'] = ltp
```

Answer (score 0):

the page should exist, it works for me
This is a classic error: use .loc[] instead of [][]

Comment: ` raise IndexingError(key) from e
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: ('ltp', 0      False`  i am getting this error